# Regarding views and gesture recognizers

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

So I have somewhat of a silly requirement, I am trying to put an "easter egg" type function into the app, where if you tap a certain area 3 times, a special view controller comes up with some silly pictures, etc...

I created a UIView and added a UITapGestureRecognizer to it. but when I set the background color to "clear" (to effectively hide the view) it doesn't respond to the tap.

How can I make the view "invisible" and yet still active? I want to use a UIView because I've set it to respond to multiple taps, which is why I didn't use a UIButton

Comment: The background color shouldn't affect the view's functionality at all.  Are you sure it was working when the view was solid?  Are you sure you didn't change anything else between now and the time it was working before?

Comment: Did you set the alpha to be lower than 0.1? Because in this case, the view will not get events

Comment: @Mayosse Source, please?  Very curious to learn more about that, because I really did not think that was the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it *is* the case where alpha < 0.1 starts ignoring events (I never heard that either), you could drop in a 1x1pt custom view/control where the 1px showing has a color that matches its background and has an alpha > 0.1,

Then override:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

to return `YES` for a larger area than the 1x1 pt.